# C# code merging with enums with slight differences

Tags: c#, types, enums

I have to merge C# codes from two similar solutions but I have some issue with enums.
The projects use **.net2.0 and I have to use it as well**.
The projects have some common class that contains enum with the same name but some difference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace MyProject
{
    public enum LETTERS
    {
        non = 0,
        a = 1,
        b = 2,
        c = 3
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
    public int v = 0;
    .
    .
    .
    public LETTERS lt = 0; // my enum
     }
}
```

There are also many other uses of this "enum" like:

```
tmpChild.Type == typeof(LETTERS);

this._data.LTR = (LETTERS)valueListUpDown_LTS.Value;

AddData(new SFunc(0,typeof(LETTERS), LETTERS.A));

LETTERS letters = LETTERS.a;
```

The second project is identical  but the enum looks like this:

```
    public enum LETTERS
    {        
        a = 0,
        b = 1,
        c = 2
    }
```

There are many various uses of these enums in the code and the code has many projects that use this assembly as a refference.
I would like to know what is the best way to merge those solutions.
I think about a method that returns enum type according to string but don't know how to implement or use the returned type in all cases.

Please Advice

---------- Edit ----------

Some other constraints that I have are:

I can't use nullable type or change the enums values (i can change their names)
because in some cases there are serializers that write and read it to\from a file.

I think of using a method like this:

```
        public static Type LETTERS(string letters_type)
        {
            if (letters_type == "type_a")
                return typeof(LETTERS);
            return typeof(LETTERS_B);
    }
```

But don't know how to cast and use a Type as enum in each case
At runtime I know which version of enum I should use, that's why such method can help.

Thanks

Comment: how would the "merged" resoult look like?

Comment: i don't know of any super easy and/or standard way to handle this.  you can keep the two conflicting enums and separate them by namespace, and then update all refs to use the fully qualified name, or you can combine them and manually update the references as needed to use the merged enum correctly.  I'd recommend either of these methods before trying to create some kind of "parameterized polymorphic enum", which would not be a standard C# enum.

Comment: Many thanks, different namespace could be an option.
I have edited my question and added some constraints that I have

Answer (score 3):

If your main intention is to merge the two codebases and remove the duplication, I would firstly use Resharper to rename one of the enums in one of the projects, then merge the codebases then I would replace all of the references to the second enum (the one without "non") to reference the first enum, and ensure I "+1" them.

I think that you might also consider a nullable enum, rather than the "magic" 0 value. I am not sure if this was available in .net 2.0 though. Also, beware of using auto-mappers when using nullable enums, they can set the values to zero if you're not careful.

Comment: Resharper isn't needed to rename a type solution-wide, is it? That's built into Visual Studio.

Comment: I think resharper is more thorough though.

Comment: Many Thanks!
I have edited my question and added some constraints that I have